# How can I know the file name and path of the html page I got when I inspect a web page?

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on an angular client on the standard local URL http://localhost:4200/.
If I inspect a web page (right click on mouse) I got in the "element" tab of the DevTool on Microsoft Edge the HTML compiled. Let's suppose I have to edit the source file associeted with that particular html code I got when inspecting a point of the web page. There is a way to get the file path to reach the file containing that piece of code?

Comment: Click on sources and you see the files involved.

Comment: The source tab is ordered relative to the baseUrl, so (on Chrome at least) you will have a folder called localhost:4200 and for example a subfolder called assets/img. So `localhost:4200/assets/img/logo.png` will be a path.

Comment: This answer might be helpful [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52997049/find-original-source-file-path-from-inspect-element-in-dev-tools]

Comment: SHIKHAR, you got the point. The question is similar to mine but the answer is not the solution. I can't only use sources on devtools because it doesn't point to the particular inspected html.